# view the item without hovering over it

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dom, bots

i should scrape messenger with selenium. In particular, I should make an element appear that only appears when you hover over it with the cursor. I leave some photos below.

[when the cursor hovers over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6OWb.jpg)

[the cursor is not over the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsKCw.jpg)

I'm trying to make that element appear without going over it, maybe with javascript if possible, or with some characteristics of selenium. Even hovering over it if neither of the above two options are available. Someone could help me pls.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `hovering over` the element is not good for you while `using the mouse` is OK? What kind of `using the mouse` if not hovering over the element will work here?

Comment: I expressed myself badly even though that was the concept. If possible I would prefer to avoid hovering over it and use another method

Comment: OK, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium supports simulation of mouse actions like mouse hover, mouse click etc.
To do so you will need this import:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Initialize `actions` object

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

define web element you want to hover over it, something like

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.button_class')
```

And then you can hover over this element with

```py
actions.move_to_element(button).perform()
```